# Why emplace_back does matter?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct T{
    T(){
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }
    ~T(){
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }   
};

int main() {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.push_back(T());
    vec.push_back(T());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
(1)Constructor
(2)Destructor
(3)Constructor
(4)Destructor
(5)Destructor
(6)Destructor
(7)Destructor
```

Why there is so much desructors calls? I see that:

(1) consruct temporary object temp1

(2) destruct temp1

(3) consruct temporary object temp2

(4) destruct temp2

Then it was called copy constructor or move constructor for temp1 and temp 2. So, (5) and (6) are clear. But what about (7)?

Comment: Also instrument a copy constructor; that may prove illuminating. Also, it would help to print something before, after and in between `push_back` calls - this way you'd know when, in response to what actions, these constructors and destructors happen.

Comment: Did you mean to call emplace_back once and push_back once? Don't see the point calling push_back twice and it doesn't match your title.

Comment: When vector needs to grow its storage, it allocates new (larger) chunk of memory, copies or moves the original elements to the new storage, then destroys the originals and deallocates old memory. The extra destructor call is likely coming from that.

Comment: Call `reserve` first?

Comment: `emplace_back` matters for "move only" types (like `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: A vector is perfectly usable for move only types even without `emplace_back`. There is an overload of `push_back` which takes an r-value reference.

Comment: You may find [this version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/698506b9fa88f528) more enlightening.  Try it with the `vec.reserve(10);` line both commented and uncommented.  When it's uncommented, the last three will show what `emplace_back()` does that `push_back()` doesn't, with the last two in particular directly comparing the two functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's expand your structure a bit:

```
struct T {
    T() {
        std::cout << "Constructor\n";
    }

    T(const T&) {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n";
    }

    T(T&&) {
        std::cout << "Move Constructor\n";
    }

    ~T() {
        std::cout << "Destructor\n";
    }
};
```

And separate calls to `push_back` method:

```
vec.push_back(T()); // 1
std::cout << "--- --- ---\n";

vec.push_back(T()); // 2
std::cout << "--- --- ---\n";
```

Now the output looks more complete:

```
Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
--- --- ---
Constructor
Move Constructor
Copy Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
--- --- ---
Destructor
Destructor
```

The first group:

```
Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
```

corresponds to the first `push_back` call:

```
vec.push_back(T()); // 1
```

The output might be decrypted easily:

```
Constructor // Create a temporary
Move Constructor // Move a temporary into the internal vector storage
Destructor // Destroy a temporary
```

The second group:

```
Constructor
Move Constructor
Copy Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

corresponds to the second `push_back` call:

```
vec.push_back(T()); // 2
```

and a little bit more complicated:

```
Constructor // create a temporary
Move Constructor // move it into the newly allocated vector storage
Copy Constructor // copy previously created element into the new storage
Destructor // destroy old storage
Destructor // destroy temporary
```

Here you should remember that *vector* class allocates its memory internally and then manages it to provide enogh space for all elements. So, if you add more elements, new allocations happen and old elements are copied or moved into the new storage.

In case of known size you might use `reserve` method, which simply reserves enough memory for a particular number of elements. It allows to avoid unnecessary memory reallocations and copying or moving elements during these reallocations on adding new elements into the vector (at least until you don't exceed the reserved size).

The third group:

```
Destructor
Destructor
```

corresponds to the *vector* `vec` destructor call at the end of the program.

Comment: This shows again how not adhering to the Rule of 3/5/0 even in test code can bite you in the ass and how you can avoid confusion by following it.

Comment: Good answer. Might be nice to show how `std::vector::reserve` affects things (very related to your comment containing about how vectors "allocate ...  memory internally and then manage it ").

Comment: @erip Yup, I've amended the answer)

Answer (score 0):

> emplace_back matters for "move only" types (like std::unique_ptr).

This is wrong and an oversimplification. Not all containers are created equally. For your vector example, if we use `reserve` the implementation can do a move assign rather than a construct, eliding our copy/extraneous destructor:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(2);
v.emplace_back(1);
v.emplace_back(1);
```

Output:

```
Constructor
Constructor
---
Destructor
Destructor
```

For a set:

```
std::set<T> s;
s.emplace(1);
s.emplace(1);
```

We get the same output. Why though? A set should theoretically construct only one object since sets are unique right? In actuality, the typical implementation constructs a temporary node in order to perform the comparison, accounting for the extra construct/destruct even though it never enters the container.

Comment: And how that relates to _question_? If you are answering to comment do it in a comment section, not answer.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I'm sorry that because I quoted a comment in my answer that it suddenly no longer answers the question. I'm glad you're here to police things.